# Linear layout above a scrollview

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I've got a simple android layout consisting of a scrollview containing a tablelayout.  This table displays properly, but I would like to add a static header above the scrollview, so that basically the labels for the columns in the table remain at the top of the screen always.  However, when I add a `<LinearLayout>` above the `<ScrollView>` in my layout file, it makes it all disappear.

Can anyone spot what I've done wrong with my xml file?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="top" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <TableLayout 
                android:id="@+id/mainTable"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

As it is, I do not see the scrollview or table layout, but if I remove the `header` linearlayout, it displays just fine.

Comment: Why didn't you set the orientation for any of your [LinearLayouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html)?

Comment: Because that is exactly what I needed to do...make it an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LinearLayouts](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-linearlayout.html) need to have the `android:orientation` parameter set.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason that was the issue, I set the main layout to have a `vertical` orientation, and the inner one to have a `horizontal` orientation.  Now I just need to figure out why that inner layout is taking up more vertical space than needed...

Comment: Probably because both the main one and the scroll are set to `fill_parent`..!?

Comment: Well its the scrollview (set to `fill_parent`) that isnt taking up enough space.  For some reason when I set the text in some subviews of the inner `LinearLayout` it causes it to expand too much

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the orientation of the parent LinearLayout to vertical! By default is set to horizontal that's way you don't see the ScrollView.

and you can try this:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="0"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" android:layout_weight="1">

        <TableLayout 
            android:id="@+id/mainTable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </ScrollView>
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Your scrollview's layout_height is set to fill_parent. Use wrap_content.

Comment: Also use wrap_content for your TableLayout's height. I suppose that was given in my answer, but apparently not.